# Evaluation of a limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^n} \Bigg\{ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{2^n}}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}}\Bigg\}$
Evaluation of this limit using integration as the limit of a sum doesn't work here. Is there any other way of doing this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: This is just a subsequence of a sum approximating $\int_0^{1} \frac  1 {\sqrt {1-x}}dx$. So the limit is $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. A simple but wonderful idea which did not occur to me.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning why here Riemann sums converge to the value of an improper integral.